# How can I block a buttons size, independently of its texts size?

Tags: html, css

so I am trying to do make my buttons like this.[image]
I have tried creating containers for each button group and setting their padding to 50px 60px per say, but that did not work and they still stretch.

I have this: [image]

Here is the code:

```css
.container5 {
  background-image: url("servicos.svg");
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.container5 .underline {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(220,52,52);
}

.container5 h1 {
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10vh;
  weight: 950;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #000;
}

.container5 .btn-group {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 5vw;
}

.container5 .btn-group button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #05031b;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px 35px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.container5 .btn-group .btn-group-ls {
  font-size: 10px;
}


.container5 .btn-group2 {
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  padding: 40px 30px;
}

.container5 .btn-group2 button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #05031b;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container5 .btn-group3 {
  margin-top: 3vh;
}

.container5 .btn-group3 button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #05031b;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container5" id="servicos">
  <h1><u class="underline">Ser</u>viços </h1>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button>VIDEO AULAS</button>
    <button>
      LIVES DIARIAS
      <br>
      <div class="btn-group-ls">
        (ANALISE DO MERCADO)
      </div>
    </button>
    <button>SALA DE SINAIS</button>
    <div>
      <div class="btn-group2">
        <button>
          LIVES SEMANAIS
          <br>
          <div class="btn-group-ls">
            (RESTROSPECTIVA DO MERCADO)
          </div>
        </button>
        <button>
          LIVES SEMANAIS
          <br>
          <div class="btn-group-ls">
            (PARA DUVIDAS)
          <!-- Edit by tacoshy: Missing a div closing tag here -->
        </button>
        <button>MATERIAIS DIDATICOS</button>
          <div>
            <div class="btn-group3">
              <button>FERRAMENTAS DE AUXILIO</button>
              <button>
                PREMIAÇÃO POR
                <br>
                DESEMPENHO (MENSAL)
              </button>
              <button>PROGRAMA DE TALENTOS</button>
              <div>
                <!-- Edit by tacoshy: as you see missing a lot closing tags -->
 </section>
```

How do I make the buttons like those ones from the 1st image? Mine's sizes aren't stable and will change if the sentences are too big. Any ideas guys?
Thank you.

**EDIT**

I managed to align all of the buttons, however,  any guess on how to level the buttons? Those who have more text are a few pixels lower than the rest.
[image]

Comment: You can simply apply `width` and `height` settings to them

Comment: hi, you have a few issues with your HTML code, you miss a few closing tags. Besides that, you proberly better off by using divs in a CSS grid or flexboxes. Since none of your buttons have an ID, I geuss you not actually needing them as a real button to fire an JS event.

Comment: ok you miss at least 7 closing tags. You might should edit your HTML code first and fix your code that it matches at least with openign and closing tags.

Comment: @Johannes Ok that worked, any guess on how to level the buttons? Those who have more text are a few pixels lower than the rest.

Comment: @tacoshy I fixed that already, thanks mate

Comment: @TomasMota Okay, I wrote an answer now, including what you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `width` and height settings to them. To make them all the same height (regardless of the different text amount in them), also add a `min-height` setting that's at least as high as the highest button.

To center-align the texts in side them properly you can use `display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` on the buttons themselves.`